# couldn't find function symbol in library

Tags: winapi, firefox-addon, smartcard, jsctypes, winscard

Declaring SCardStatus function causes the error: "couldn't find function symbol in library"

The Code is as follows:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');
var is64bit = ctypes.voidptr_t.size == 4 ? false : true;
var ifdef_UNICODE = true;
var TYPES = {
    ABI: is64bit ? ctypes.default_abi : ctypes.winapi_abi,
    CHAR: ctypes.char,
    DWORD: ctypes.uint32_t,
    LONG: ctypes.long,
    LPCVOID: ctypes.voidptr_t,
    ULONG_PTR: is64bit ? ctypes.uint64_t : ctypes.unsigned_long,
    WCHAR: ctypes.jschar,
};
TYPES.LPSTR = TYPES.CHAR.ptr;
TYPES.LPDWORD = TYPES.DWORD.ptr;
TYPES.LPWSTR = TYPES.WCHAR.ptr;
TYPES.SCARDHANDLE = TYPES.ULONG_PTR;
TYPES.LPBYTE = TYPES.LPSTR;
TYPES.LPTSTR = ifdef_UNICODE ? TYPES.LPWSTR : TYPES.LPSTR;
var cardLib = ctypes.open('Winscard');
var SCardStatus = cardLib.declare('SCardStatus', TYPES.ABI, TYPES.LONG, TYPES.SCARDHANDLE, TYPES.LPTSTR, TYPES.LPDWORD, TYPES.LPDWORD, TYPES.LPDWORD, TYPES.LPBYTE, TYPES.LPDWORD );
```

I guess that TYPES.LPBYTE is not correct, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , LPBYTE should be a Pointer to a 32-byte buffer that receives the ATR string from the currently inserted card, if available. However I could not fix it, I appreciate any helps in advanced.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, like how did you `declare` the `SCardConnect` function?

Comment: previous question solved and now my problem is about SCardStatus declaration.

Comment: The docs show this accepts characters, so on the page it shows: `  SCardStatusW (Unicode) and SCardStatusA (ANSI)` so you have to define it like this: `var SCardStatus = cardLib.declare(ifdef_UNICODE ? 'SCardStatusW' : 'SCardStatusA', ....`

Comment: OMG u r such a perfect man, really u r expert in js-ctypes, thanks

Comment: Hahah thanks but that was more of a winapi question :)

Comment: So u r also expert in winapi ;)
I want to complete the question; Using SCardStatus cause error:
can't pass ctypes.char16_t.ptr to argument 2 of long

    var szReaderName = TYPES.LPCTSTR ;
    var pcchReaderLen = TYPES.LPDWORD;
    var pdwState = TYPES.LPDWORD;
    var pdwProtocol = TYPES.LPDWORD;
    var pbAtr = TYPES.BYTE.array(parseInt(64))();
    var pcbAtrLen = TYPES.LPDWORD;
    var rez_SCS = SCardStatus(cardHandle, szReaderName, pcchReaderLen, pdwState, pdwProtocol,pbAtr , pcbAtrLen);

Comment: can you please post your full code, on github or something so i can track your work to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In winapi if the functions have two versions, unicode version and ascii verison IF it takes strings. So the docs show this accepts characters, so on the page it shows: `SCardStatusW (Unicode) and SCardStatusA (ANSI)` so you have to define it like this: `var SCardStatus = cardLib.declare(ifdef_UNICODE ? 'SCardStatusW' : 'SCardStatusA', ....`

Comment: you mean if we declare a winapi function which takes a string as its input, we have to determine the type of this string, Ascii or Unicode.